# Why are my loop-generated Keras sequential models all exactly the same?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I would like to train multiple models all with the same hyper-parameters until I get one that is is sufficiently accurate. I expect slight deviations in performance due to the initial weights being randomly set when the model is created.

Each time I ru my program the first CNN has a different accuracy, as I would expect. However subsequent CNNs all perform exactly the same as the first CNN. I am clearing the keras session, and 'deleting' the model at every iteration. I am not setting any random seeds to fixed values.

Here is the section of code where I generate the networks (in Python 3.6)

```
def reset_weights(model):
        session = keras.backend.get_session()
        for layer in model.layers: 
             for v in layer.__dict__:
                 v_arg = getattr(layer,v)
                 if hasattr(v_arg,'initializer_run'):
                     initializer_method = getattr(v_arg, 'initializer')
                     initializer_method.run(session=session)
                     print('reinitializing layer {}.{}'.format(layer.name, v))

def  train_models(input_dir, output_dir, roi_file):
            error = 1.0
            roi_info = read_ROI_file(roi_file)
            x_data, y_data = generate_data_set(input_dir, roi_info)

            while (error > 0.001):
                keras.backend.clear_session()
                the_net = define_model()
                reset_weights(the_net)
                the_history = train_model(the_net, x_data, y_data, num_epochs=100)
                error = the_history.history['val_loss'][-1]
                print("Model accuracy : {:7.5f}".format(error))
            if error < 0.002:
                the_time = datetime.now()
                net_name = os.path.join(output_dir, "bayer_net_{:s}_acc={:7.5f}".format(
                    the_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"), error))
                print("Saved as: {:s}\n\n".format(net_name))

                the_net.save("{:s}.h5".format(net_name))
                plot_history(the_history, "{:s}.png".format(net_name))    
            else:
                print ("Not saving the model.\n\n")
            the_net = None
```